# Create long binary string using PACK in chunks in PHP

Tags: php, pack, unpack

I'm trying to communicate between an embedded device and server, where the server code is written in PHP. I've been able to do so using pack() function, which I'm able to get working. However, now, I want to send a really long packet, and the packet itself is such that it contains N entries of some schedule. So I have to send the info of "N" before iterating those many times and then have to send each of the schedule.

Now, I was trying to see if concatenation of output of pack() could help me accomplish the task, since then, I'll be able to do something like this:

```
// Pack EPOCH & Number of Schedules
$pkt = pack("Nn", time(), $num_schedule);
// Now iterate
$i = 0;
while($i < $num_schedule) {
   $schedule_time = $schedule[$i]["time"]  // Start Time in epoch for one day
   $schedule_weekday = $schedule[$i]["weekday"]  // Contains 0-6
   // Pack individual entry, concatenate!
   $pkt .= pack("nn", $schedule_time, $weekday);  
   $i++;
}
```

But the concatenation does not work as expected (as confirmed by unpacking on embedded device). I suspect some "endian-ness" may be at play?

Can some one tell me why simple concatenation doesnt work. Also, how to fix this problem?